# Matlab and obliqueslice: Rotating around arbitrary z-axis

Tags: matlab, image-processing, slice, surface, image-rotation

I have a question about using the [obliqueslice function in Matlab](https://nl.mathworks.com/help/images/ref/obliqueslice.html). I have a 3D matrix with image data and want to create radial slices through this volume. The user defines a axis: a coordinate with a x and y value (p_x and p_y). The function then creates a slice through the volume with reference to this given point and a normal vector.

I thought that by rotating the normal vector around the z-axis I would get the right slices, but in this way, the slices are rotated around their own axis as well. The retreived slice does not stay in one orientation.

```
p_x = pos(1);
p_y = pos(2);
p_z = 0;


th = linspace(0,pi,n_a+1);
th(end)=[];
x_0 = 10;
y_0 = 0;
xunit = x_0 * cos(th) - y_0 * sin(th);
yunit = x_0 * sin(th) + y_0 * cos(th);

data = struct;

figure
colormap(gray)
plot3(p_x,p_y,p_z,'or','MarkerFaceColor','r'); %plot point in volume
grid on
xlabel('x-axis')
ylabel('y-axis');
zlabel('z-axis');

hold on

for k = 1:1:length(th)
    
    plot3(xunit(k),yunit(k),0,'ob','MarkerFaceColor','b'); %plot normal
    [B,x,y,z] = obliqueslice(im, [p_x, p_y, p_z], [xunit(k) yunit(k) p_z], 'OutputSize','Full');
    data(k).th = th(k);
    data(k).B = B;
    data(k).x = x;
    data(k).y = y;
    data(k).z = z;
    
    surf(x,y,z,B,'EdgeColor','None');

    pause(1)
    drawnow
end
```

As said: p_x and p_y are the coordinates of the rotating axis , p_z is zero, because I don't want to rotate around an height. xunit and yunit are the normal vectors, rotating around the z-axis, so here the z-coordinate is also zero. The number of slices is given by n_a. Because the slice goes through the whole volume, the steps in angle difference is done with linspace n_a+1 and then removing the last value, because this would give the same slice as the first.

Is this the right way to rotate around an axis using obliqueslice? I did the same thing using the surf and slice functions, but because then I have to formulate the size of the surface first, this is not ideal. Obliqueslice automatically creates the right size of the surface.

Comment: I don't get this part here: for `th(1) = 0`, then `[p_x, p_y]` is equal to `[xunit(1) yunit(1)]` right ? So how can we determine an axis with only one single point ?

Comment: No, p_x and p_y are both given by the user and is a coordinate through which a plane must cross and is in every . This plane stands orthogonal on the normal vector given by xunit and yunit, which rotates around the z-axis.